# How to test custom file upload React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a React component to upload files. Below is part of the code that handles the file selection and once files are selected, it will display thumbnails.

I want to use RTL to test the file selection: clicking button which is `EvidenceUploaderPanel`, this opens the file selector input element, then choosing files.

This will also make the requests to upload the files as they are selected.

But I have no idea how to start.

```
function UploadScreen({
  title,
  maxNumberOfUploadFiles = 3,
  acceptedFileTypes,
}: Props) {
  const [documents, setDocuments] = useState<FileObject[]>([]);


  const handleFileSelection = (files: FileList) => {

    const documentsWithThumbnails = Array.from(files).map((file) => {
      // here I also make a request to upload each file.
      return {
        file,
        thumbnailURL: URL.createObjectURL(file),
        name: file.name,
      };
    });
    setDocuments((currentDocuments) => [...currentDocuments, ...documentsWithThumbnails]);
  };

  const inputRef = useRef(
    (() => {
      const element = document.createElement('input');
      element.multiple = true;
      element.type = 'file';
      element.accept = acceptedFileTypes?.join(',') || IMAGE_MIME_TYPES.join(',');
      element.addEventListener('change', () => {
        if (element.files && documents.length + element.files.length < maxNumberOfUploadFiles) {
          handleFileSelection(element.files);
          element.value = '';
        }
      });

      return element;
    })(),
  );


  const handleOpenFileClicker = () => {
    inputRef.current.click();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2 className="container">{title}</h2>
       {documents.length > 0 ? (
        <section>
          <div className="body-text">
           Add files
          </div>
          <div className="thumbnail-container">
            {documents.map((doc) => {
              return (
                <BaseThumbnail
                  src={doc?.thumbnailURL}
                  key={doc.name}
                  deleteAction={() => {
                    deleteDocument(doc.name);
                  }}
                />
              );
            })}
          </div>
          <Link onPress={handleOpenFileClicker}>
            Add photos
          </Link>
        </section>
      ) : (
        <section>
          <div className="text">
            Add files
          </div>
          <div className="upload-container" />
          <EvidenceUploaderPanel
            labelText="upload files"
            openFilePicker={handleOpenFileClicker}
          />
        </section>
       )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I don't see any point in checking the functionality of the file selection - it's browser-based and it will work. As for the sending function, it can be checked, but taking into account mock. First of all, ask yourself what you will get by checking it with a test other than a +1 test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you thought about maybe using [cypress](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/getting-started/writing-your-first-test#Add-a-test-file) for this?
They have a nice built in function that does exactly what you want and the setup Is really easy.

I’d recommend you using the [cypress component testing for react](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2021/04/06/cypress-component-testing-react/), they have an entire page on their website’s docs explaining how to set it up. And than you can just mount the file selection component and use their [`cy.selectFile()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/selectfile) method.

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

In RTL, the problem can be solved by following only relevant steps:

1. Import 'userEvent' from RTL (`@testing-library/user-event`)
2. Mock. Create file using "`new File(['test'], 'test.txt', {type: 'text/plain'})`"
3. Render.
4. Grab file object by any of getXXX like `getByLabel`.
5. Provide file(s) created to file object using "`userEvent.upload(fileObject, file)`"
6. Assert "`expect fileObject.files.length.toBe(1)`"